# What was the dominant government system in the 1600s~1800s?

Tags: government, early-modern, industrial-revolution

I'm making a game where the player begins with small tribe in Ancient Era and for each era there are government systems to choose. They are very similar to the ones from the Civilization series. Below are the eras I have in my game for some reference.

- Ancient Era (BC4000 ~ BC1600)
- Classical Era (BC1600 ~ AD0)
- Medieval Era (AD0 ~ AD1300)
- Early Modern Era (AD1300 ~ AD1600)
- Industrial Era (AD1600 ~ AD1800)
- Contemporary Era (AD1800~)

I will not talk about the first two eras, as they are irrelevant. Once the Medieval Era begins, the player is prompt to choose one of the following government systems.

1. **Monarchy**
2. **Medieval Republic** (Through some research, I found out there were various different types of republics in Medieval era, mostly very small and temporary, but still significant) (Just named it myself..  lol)
3. **Theocracy**

For Early Modern Era,

1. **Absolute Monarchy** (With the influence of religions decreases,
   monarchy was temporarily strengthened.)
2. **Maritime Republic** (Inspired by Italian republics in this era. e.g. Republic of Genoa)
3. **Ecclesiarchy**

What I have for Contemporary Era are,

1. **Democracy**
2. **Communism**
3. **Fascism**

But I don't know what to do with Industrial Era(1600~1800).

Maybe some early forms of 3 contemporary era governments? or any less significant but once existed form of government in 1600~1800s?

Comment: I'm not sure you can "map" industrialisation with a specific form of government like that. The UK, the first industrial nation, was a constitutional monarchy (in reality, an oligarchy) as was Germany. The USA was a democracy, France - less industrialised - was everything from a monarchy, a Republic, a mess, an autocracy (Napoleon) to a monarchy then a Republic. It's not linear.

Comment: The date ranges of a couple of eras seem a little off. Your Medieval era starts about 500 years too early. The industrial era is about 150 years too early.

Comment: Thank you for your question; could you give us an overview of the [research you have done so far](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599) and explain what you find to be unclear or missing? Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) may be helpful.

Comment: Which country? Which continent?  This is going to generate argument over whether the UK is a constitutional monarchy, a constitutional monarchy or some other classification determined by the predilections of the individual historian.  There is no standard taxonomy, and reality is _always_ more complex than the taxonomy (see box's law).  Strongly recommend that the question be supported by more research.

Comment: Well, this is not bound to any country or continent. It's just everything combined, or maybe I can say many different but significant parts of humankind combined. Also, this is just a game, so I can go more creative, than arguing to come up with something most accurate. As far as I understand, history is all about perspective, so I guess I will do more research and take account of answers here as well.

Comment: Yes, I'm actually aware of the fact that the years of eras are not very accurate for medieval era and industrial era, and possibly ancient era as well. That was something I just had to compromise to be easier for the players.

Comment: I'm not trying to connect the forms of government directly to the industrialisation. Name of the eras are just how I classified the year spans, so I just need 3 forms of governments that were dominant in that time frame.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/16th_century) says that the dominant form of government in 1600 was autocracy. the [Ming Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ming_dynasty) in China,  Sultanates in India, and the Ottoman Caliphate covering another large population group.  Arguably your three forms of government are [water empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydraulic_empire), theocracy and autocracy.

Comment: You'll get a lot more answers in [Worldbuilding Stack Exchange](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/), a site designed specifically for questions like this.  Later, when your general structure is well defined, you might come back here to ask ask about specific details that you can't find elsewhere.

Comment: @RayButterworth, Worldbuilding declined the migration.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. **Limited Democracy**
   Something like the English parliament, with the franchise for the legislature (or just one chamber) extended to *rich, male, respectable* commoners. There might still be a monarch at the head of the executive, but the commoners have conquered the *power of the purse*.
2. **Ideological Dictatorship**
   Either a theocracy, just without the *established* hierarchy (lay politicians or lower clergy control the mob through religious fervor), or something similar for secular reasons. Cromwell or the French Revolution.
3. **Enlightened Despotism**
   A monarch with absolutist powers encounters *enlightened* philosophers and starts to rule in what *he* perceives to be the best interest of the citizens. The citizens are not consulted ... Catherine II of Russia, Frederick the Great of Prussia, arguably Peter the Great of Russia.

Answer (score 3):

I understand programming loves rules, but the real world is a messy place. Who says there has to really be only one dominant system?

That period you call out is also known as [The Enlightenment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_Enlightenment), which was a time of great social experimentation, particularly with a new political concept called [Liberalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberalism)<sup>*</sup>. Some nations were down with it, many weren't, but this is where the discussion was in Western countries.

Classic Liberalism is more of a spectrum than a boolean thing. What I often see done with the era is measuring a country's Liberalism level by the % of residents who had the right to vote. This can be misleading though, as some countries would try to placate the movement by giving citizens a vote in largely powerless assemblies.

The two poles in this view of society were "Liberal" and "Reactionary" (or if you prefer "Illiberal")

However, The Enlightenment was largely limited to Europe and European-peopled colonies abroad. Most of the world during this entire period went on with governments largely similar to those they had before.

---

<sup>* - We typically refer to this as "Classic Liberalism", to differentiate Enlightenment usage from common modern usage, which is rather different.</sup>

Comment: If nothing else, "The Enlightenment" gets top marks for clever positioning...